# how to create a shortcut to unlock my pc

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

So basically how do i add a shortcut to unlock my pc when it is locked without having to type my password and i was wondering if it is possible to remove password from the lock screen so it only works if you use the shortcut.

Comment: ...but how would you use the shortcut if your screen is locked?

Comment: i didnt know that you couldnt use shortcuts if its locked

Comment: I don't understand… Do you want to disable session locking? Because a shortcut to circumvent the session lock authentication would effectively be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set short cut to login but you can set user with no user following the steps given below.

First, if your user has sudo privileges, you must enable its NOPASSWD option. Otherwise, sudo will ask for a password even when you don't have one, and won't accept an empty password.

To do so, open the sudoers configuration file with sudo visudo, and add the following line to the file,

```
User_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Close the editor to apply the changes, and test the effect on sudo in a new terminal.

Delete the password for your user by running this command, replacing david with your username:

```
sudo passwd user_name -d
```

If you ever get prompted for a password, just type enter and it should work.

Note : You can use GUI to select Log in without a password option from user accounts

Comment: i just wanted a shortcut like ctrl + alt + anykey to unlock my computer without having to type my password everytime but it looks like its not possible anyway,thank you for putting effort in answering my question